# Why is delayed job not creating a 'handler' when I use delay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm trying to use delayed job for the first time in my rails 3 app.

I have a method that looks something like this, which calls a long running method which I want to put into the delayed job queue.

```
def complete_order()
    self.paid_at = Time.now
    self.delay.long_running_stuff
end
```

The result of running this method is an entry in my delayed_jobs table with a `NULL` value in the `handler` field.

I have no idea why and can't think of how to debug this. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is complete_order a method on an ActiveRecord model? What does the long_running_stuff method look like?

Comment: I've discovered a questions which solves my problem, mine should be considered a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966006/delayed-job-2-1-4-error-job-failed-to-load-instance-of-io-needed-handler-ni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was attr_accessible

I found a solution here http://groups.google.com/group/delayed_job/browse_thread/thread/60b6ae55a3304c08